# Stop user from typing into input field after certain character limit with PURE JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have to use JS. This is for an assignment.

This is my code:

```
var bio = document.getElementById('bio');
var charsLeft = document.getElementById('charsLeft');
bio.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var remaining;
    var perm = bio.value;
    remaining = 139 - bio.value.length;
    charsLeft.innerHTML = remaining;
    if (remaining == 0) {
        bio.value = perm;
    }
}
```

It does not stop the user from typing stuff after the charsLeft is 0.

PLEASE DO NOT MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE!

THIS IS THE ONLY PURE JAVASCRIPT APPROACH I COULD FIND

Comment: You can do this with HTML. Just use like <input type="text" maxlength="5" /> You are allowed to type maximum of 5 characters here.

Comment: Attach an input event. On input, make sure the length of the value of the input isn't pas the limit. If it is, cancel the event.

Comment: @user2584538 I have to use javascript.

Comment: @AndrewLi What do you mean "input" event?

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from this line: `bio.value = perm;` because if I add an alert or change the value in any other way it works fine.

Comment: Instead of doing "bio.value = perm", do evt.preventDefault() then.

Comment: Why the dislikes?

Comment: @Davy That was it! Thank you!

Comment: I did not dislike, but i guess its because there is no real advantage of doing this in javascript. I think you are only adding complexity without any real value. But i do not know the full usecase.

Comment: This is for an assignment. I have to do it this way.

Comment: It is not working anymore. The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evgzb2qr/

Answer (score 5):

You dont actually need javascript to do this :

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" maxlength="100">
```

Comment: I have to use javascript. I am not using an HTML approach.

Comment: @Ianardo Why do you *have* to?

Comment: Because you can always just inspect element it and change it.

Comment: @Ianardo You can do that with JavaScript too! It's client side!

Comment: If i change the id of that input control, your javascript will also stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```